# Waiting for elements with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, synchronization

I am automating a web page that essentially has a button which, each time it is pressed, creates a new text field.
I am using the FindBy annotation with PageFactory to find the list of text fields.

I have a synchronization problem when I press the button several times, thus creating several text fields, and then try to write into one of them. Stepping through the debugger it works fine, but out of the debugger there is a delay before the FindBy finds all the text fields. 
My current workaround performs sleeps until the required number of text fields are found but I find this quite unsatisfactory. Any suggestions how the synchronization could best be done?

```
@FindBy(how= How.XPATH, using="//*[contains(@id, 'TextField')]")
private List<WebElement> textFields;
:
:
public void enterText(Integer index, String text){
    int attempts = 0;
    // Check every 10th of a second for 10 seconds if all the textFields have been found 
    while ((textFields.size() <= index) && attempts < 100){
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    textFields.get(index).sendKeys("blah blah");

}
```

Comment: see this http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all use Implicit wait for all element present in script.
This wait is wait for all element present in the script

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Initiate above just after `get.("URL");`

Now for specific element which need additional time you can use below code:-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Refer below:-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/

Hope it will help you :)